# User Control TextBox with Label

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, user-controls

How to make a user control which extend from TextBox ,and add a Label beside the textbox , not inside the textbox , the label must be beside it or on top of it.
BTW the user control must extend from TextBox .

For long time I have been searching for this problem and I cant find any anwser.

Comment: Post your code and show your effort. Here you have a link that will help you:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h62478z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Where are you running into trouble in your code?

Comment: We need something to reference off of. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why do you want to extend the `TextBox`? By doing so you no longer have a user control as it is of its own type. Just create a user control and put a `Label` and a `TextBox` next to each other.

Comment: I have an answer for this that I just got done writing, but I don't know if it applied because you didn't bother to mention what graphics framework you are using.

Comment: _user control which extend from TextBox_ Nope. Do look up CustomControl vs UserControl!

Comment: Guys Im sure there is a way, and Im using visual studio

Comment: _Yes, there is a way!_ Like I said: Put a `Label` and a `TextBox` next to each other in a `UserControl` and _**do not**_ inherit from the `TextBox`!

Comment: It is because of reasons like this that the `UserControl` exists: to put multiple controls together in a single one!

Comment: I already tried this way, but the problem is I cant resize the textbox, its size with be fixed.That why I want to extent it from textbox, so I can resize the textbox freely in the design mode..

Comment: Tip: anchor the controls inside the UserControl then resize **it**

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to place a `Label` next to a `TextBox`.  If you want to do this with code, it's as simple as:

```
int x, y;
x = y = 200;
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Width = 100;
tb.Left = x;
tb.Top = y;

Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Width = 50;
//If you want it on the right of the TextBox
lbl.Left = tb.Right + 10;
//If you want it on the left of the TextBox
lbl.Right = tb.Left - 10;
```

You can obviously modify all of those values to your hearts desire.  Also, this seems kind of moot, because if you're going to be doing this in a `WinForms` Application, you can just drag and drop everything you want in to place.  You're obviously new to this...  Check out some YouTube on how to create WinForms Applications and get on MSDN...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DdXrw6HUzCA

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dn308572.aspx

Comment: Thank for your help, but my idea is to use one control which is the TextBox with the Label. And when I drag and drop this control to the WinForm it should add a textbox with the label.